# Swift Error. returns Thread: 26 EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift

from time to time im getting this error EXC_BAD_ACCESS, let me explain what is happening.

I have this function that writes 100 times per second to a string in real time.

```
private func startAccelerometerUpdates() {
    // Make sure the accelerometer hardware is available.
    motion.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0 / frequency // 60 Hz or 100 HZ
    motion.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: operationQueue) { (data, error) in
      guard let accelerometerData = data, error == nil else { return }
      let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
      let currentTimestamp = Timestamp(timestamp: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
      let currentAcceleration = SensorData(timestamp: currentTimestamp, x: (acceleration.x) * -9.81, y: acceleration.y * -9.81, z: acceleration.z * -9.81)
      self.accelerometerDataString += currentAcceleration.description 
    }
  }
```

This error pops in the last line where I increment the string self.accelerometerDataString. I have a timer that writes the content of the string to a file, from 30 to 30 seconds. This errors happens RIGHT after I write that string to a file and remove all elements from that string. Heres the code that the timer triggers

```
  if(isAccelerometerRunning == true && !accelerometerDataString.isEmpty){
      accelerometerDataFileService?.writeDataToFile(dataToWrite: accelerometerDataString)
      accelerometerDataString = ""
    }
```

I believe that the bad access error happens when I do accelerometerDataString = "", while the string is still being updated, but im not sure. Does somebody know what can be happening?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you repro with Address Sanitizer and Thread Sanitizer, what do they reveal?

Comment: @Shadowrun yes I can, I just need to wait until it happens again